# Can't get Javascript onload to fire

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function for a web site I need to fire as soon as the page loads.

I can actually get the function to fire by attaching it to an event like onkeyup.  I just can't get it to fire when the page loads.

Another weird thing - it fires when I run the app on my local server - just not when I deploy to the production server.

Here's my function.  Like I said it works fine if I have it fire as the result of an onkeyup event - both locally and on the prod server.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setDefaultRadioButton(){
        alert("in setDefaultRadioButton()!!!");
        document.getElementById("Active").checked = true;
    }
</script>
```

Here's where I try to invoke it using onload().  Like I said it fires when I run the app on my local server - just not when I deploy it to the production server...

```
<body onload="javascript:setDefaultRadioButton();">
```

I've tried just about everything I can think of - it just won't fire.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `window.onload`. It is more appropriate for your case and inline javascript is not very good practice.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        setDefaultRadioButton();
    }
</script>
```